# max weight that the shimano Rs400 can carry ?

Tags: wheels, rims, weight

I am intending to buy the shimano RS400 pair of wheels to replace my 20 spokes wheels. I intend to use them for touring and commuting when an expected heavy luggage.  Was wondering the maximum weight that these pair of wheels can handle. and how to know in general ?.

Comment: I only know Rs400 as a hub.  The wheels and spokes come into play.   You should ask the builder / supplier of the wheel.

Comment: The hub appears to be available in 32 and 36 hole versions.  The 36-hole hub with suitable rims, properly built, should be able to handle at least a "medium" touring load -- perhaps not ideal for crossing Australia, but fine for loaded road touring in most of the US.

Comment: Weight rating are on rims not hubs. Competition rims can be below 90 kg. Is RS400 an actual shimano wheel set? I've only seen R10, R500 etc.

Comment: yup [this one](http://www.rosebikes.com/article/road-wheel-set-28700c-xtreme-airline-4--shimano-hb-fh-rs400/aid:202988)

Comment: actually one of the reviewers in the previous link says he has tried it for half a year with a moving load of 110kgs

Comment: It depends a lot on how you ride too. Riding like a hooligan will make even strong wheels not last.

Comment: @HadyElsahar it's a wheelset built from RS400 hub and rim and spokes from completely different manufacturers.

Comment: Well build wheel should have little stressed to the hub ( spoke tension can crack the flange) . Most of the weight pressure will put on the rims and tyres.

Answer (score 1):

Shimano RS400 is pretty old now - I know my 1998 frame had the wheelset new.

Here's a photo of my rear hub.  I can't show the front hub because that was replaced with an WH-R560 by a previous owner.   Why it was replaced, I don't know - it was either a speed optimisation or a failure where a new wheel was better than fixing the original.

[image]

Generally speaking, touring wheels are built for strength not speed.  So touring wheels should be at least 32 spokes on the front and more would not be bad.